# how to use AlchemyAPI in c# Sentiment Analysis

Tags: c#, alchemyapi

I want to get Sentiment Analysis of text data using alchemyapi, for that I am trying following c# api. But I have problem which function should be call in my project to pass parameter and take JSON result in return.
https://github.com/AlchemyAPI/alchemyapi_csharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples in the "examples" directory will show you how to use the SDK.  This will get you started, though the C# SDK doesn't appear to support JSON output from the server (probably because that would require the inclusion of an extra dependency).

If you need it to return JSON, you would just make an HTTP GET or POST request to a URL.  An example of this might look like this:

http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/url/URLGetTextSentiment?apikey=ENTER_YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&url=www.cnn.com&showSourceText=1&outputMode=json

Don't forget to change the value for the "apikey" field.